# How can I install PySide on Travis?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, travis-ci, python-3.4

My tests for [Quamash](https://github.com/aknuds1/quamash) depend on [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/pyside) (or PyQt eventually) for Python 3.4, so I'm wondering how I can install this dependency on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) so that it's available to the tests?

I am aware that I can install PySide from source via pip, but that is a very slow process.

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: does `travis-retry sudo apt-get install python3-pyside` work for you? Note you also need to add `virtualenv:
  system_site_packages: true`

Comment: @Will Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried implementing it, but for some reason Travis hasn't reacted to the new commit and tried to build it (I've noticed not all commits lead to new builds in general). I'll see if I can get a build running later.

Comment: @Will Where do you add the `virtualenv: system_site_packages: true` part? I tried to add it to the top level of .travis.yml, but turns out it was invalid.

Comment: Check out scikit-learn's [.travis.yml](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/.travis.yml) and their [install script](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/continuous_integration/install.sh). You can also syntax check your `.travis.yml` with [WebLint](http://lint.travis-ci.org/)

Comment: @Will I've modified [.travis.yml](https://github.com/aknuds1/quamash/blob/440cdeff6a58d283635e33880c1c0cd114f9052c/.travis.yml) so that it looks good now, but the `system_site_packages: true` setting [breaks the build](https://travis-ci.org/aknuds1/quamash/builds/28988810) :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Installing via apt-get is currently not possible. See [github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2219#issuecomment-41804942) and [travis docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#Travis-CI-Uses-Isolated-virtualenvs).

Three other options.

### Just use pip

Your `.travis.yml` will include:

```
install:
  - pip install PySide
```

As you mentioned, it will take a LONG time to build PySide from source on the travis-ci servers. However, this method is guaranteed to work.

### Wait for Travis CI to update to Ubuntu 14.04

[Issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2046). Python3.4 is included in Ubuntu 14.04. Then, your `.travis.yml` could look like:

```
install:
    - sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

### Build your own wheel

You can build your own PySide [wheel](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) so Travis-CI builds using Python3.4 do not have to build PySide from source.

Following these [instructions](http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html), I built a PySide wheel by:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup.git pyside-setup
$ cd pyside-setup
$ python3.4 setup.py bdist_wheel --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 --version=1.2.2
```

You can then host this wheel somewhere, and access it using travis by:

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
  - pip install PySide --no-index --find-links https://<your-site>;
  # Travis CI servers use virtualenvs, so we need to finish the install by the following
  - python ~/virtualenv/python${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

where `<your-site>` is a webpage that contains a link to the wheel named `PySideXXXXXXX.whl`, with the correct [naming convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention). Use `--no-index` to prevent pip from finding and installing a newer PySide from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

#### I went ahead and tried this, basic usage works!

See the [source](https://github.com/parkin/python-wheelhouse).

The wheel is hosted at the repo's [gh-pages](http://parkin.github.io/python-wheelhouse/).

Note on my machine with Ubuntu 14.04, building the wheel created the file `dist/PySide-1.2.2-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl` which was roughly 17 MB. When I instead included the `--standalone` tag in the build step, the file was ~77 MB.

Note that as of yet, only `import PySide` has been tested. Due to this being built under Ubuntu 14.04 and Travis-Ci servers running Ubuntu 12.04, I do not know how functional the PySide library is. If you run into problems, you may want to redo this on a machine running Ubuntu 12.04.

Update:

The following python script

```
import PySide
from PySide import QtGui
```

[fails](https://travis-ci.org/parkin/python-wheelhouse/builds/29623008) when the PySide wheel was built on Ubuntu 14.04. See [the failure](https://travis-ci.org/parkin/python-wheelhouse/jobs/29623010). However, it succeeds when PySide is built on Ubuntu 12.04, see [the success](https://travis-ci.org/parkin/python-wheelhouse/jobs/29623009).

#### Using my PySide wheel

In your .travis.yml file, include the following:

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
  - pip install PySide --no-index --find-links https://parkin.github.io/python-wheelhouse/;
  # Travis CI servers use virtualenvs, so we need to finish the install by the following
  - python ~/virtualenv/python${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the thorough write-up!

Comment: Thanks for the writeup! I tried to install PySide using a standalone wheel in a conda environment, and I couldn't get it to work. Turns out I just needed to run `python pyside_postinstall.py -install`

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use the [caching feature](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) of Travis to cache wheels across builds.

Adding

```
language: python
cache: pip
```

to your `.travis.yml` caches `$HOME/.cache/pip`. As such, the PySide wheel will be built once and persist across rebuilds of your application.